# How do i rotate the camera 180 Degrees to look back when a player holds down the space bar?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Im creating a game in unity where the player is able to move around a map using the arrow keys and changes direction using the mouse, But i am trying to get the camera to look back when the player holds down the space bar but keep moving forwards.

So Have this bit of code to rotate the camera 180 degrees, which is does but if i hold down the space bar if flashed as if it is switching between facing forwards and facing backwards.
How do i stop this from happening?

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && !globalScript.lookBack)
    {
        globalScript.lookBack = true;
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(14, 180, 0));
    }
    else { 
        globalScript.lookBack = false;
    }
}
```

I am also trying to make the player always move forwards even when the camera is looking backwards (I have set my player to move in the direction that the camera is facing) so In other words when the player looks back they are still moving in the same direction that they were moving in when the camera is facing forwards.

I have come up with this to switch between moving forward and -forwards depending on the camera which i think is working but i don't think the lookBack is being accessed correctly and i'm not sure why.

```
Vector3 moveDir; 

if (globalScript.lookBack)
{
    moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * -Vector3.forward;
}
else
{
    moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
}

 controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * playerMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

How do i go about trying to fix this so that i can still move forward when facing backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second block fires almost every frame, including any frame space isn't held down as well as any frame where `globalScript.lookBack` is true. You need to ensure that it only fires when both `lookBack` is true AND space isn't held down.

There also appears to be a problem where your rotation doesn't get set back to where it was before. If you change to using Quaternions this becomes easy. You can use `Quaternion.Inverse` to reverse the rotation you did to turn around, then apply that to the rotation

Altogether:

```
private void Update()
{
    Quaternion halfRot = Quaternion.Euler(14, 180, 0);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (!globalScript.lookBack)
        {
            globalScript.lookBack = true;
            transform.rotation *= halfRot;
        }
    }
    else if (globalScript.lookBack) { 
        globalScript.lookBack = false;
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Inverse(halfRot));
    }
}
```

Or, with a more "balanced" formatting:

```
private void Update()
{
    Quaternion halfRot = Quaternion.Euler(14, 180, 0);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (!globalScript.lookBack)
        {
            globalScript.lookBack = true;
            transform.rotation *= halfRot;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (globalScript.lookBack) { 
        {
            globalScript.lookBack = false;
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Inverse(halfRot));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, This solution rotates the camera correctly now the only problem that i have is that it is supposed to look back while holding space and then look forward when released but it doesn't. However if i log the bool lookBack it prints false while space is not being pressed and true only if you hold down space. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @GinoSesia I changed some things to make it look forward again

Comment: Thank you this works exactly how i wanted it to. I appreciate your help, Thank you

Comment: @GinoSesia You're welcome! Consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) by clicking on the check mark (✓) button.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with repositioning the camera. I know how move it but it is not going to where i want it to?

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about the camera's position so I'm not sure where to begin. If you were to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include some info about the problem there, I can certainly take a look.

Comment: [here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149458/how-do-you-change-the-camera-position-temporarily-and-then-revert-it-back-to-whe) to the camera position.