# How do you change the camera position Temporarily and then revert it back to where it was in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a game in unity where the player can move around a map and when they hold down the spacebar the camera rotated 180 degrees so that they are looking behind them.

When the player presses and holds down the space bar i also want the camera to move right above the player (at the moment the camera is positioned behind the player looking at the player) looking back.

This is the code that i have to rotate the camera as well as reposition the camera:

```
Quaternion halfRotation = Quaternion.Euler(14, 180, 0);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (!globalScript.lookBack)
        {
            globalScript.lookBack = true;
            transform.rotation *= halfRotation;
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.parent.position.x, transform.parent.position.y + 1, transform.parent.position.z);
        }
    }

    else if (globalScript.lookBack)
    {
        globalScript.lookBack = false;
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Inverse(halfRotation);

    }
```

I change the position of the camera which is a child of the player in the second if statement when the space bar is pressed. this moves the camera to where i want it to be when looking back but i am struggling to figure out how to put it back to its original position when space is released.

The position i want it to revert to is (0,4,-9)

How do i revert it back to this location?

Comment: The same way you moved. You can snap back or lerp back.

Comment: What's the local position of the camera normally, before the lookback happens?

Comment: the position is normally at x=0, y=4, z=-9 before look back occurs

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the camera flip action, you can store the position of the camera in a vector variable and then set it back to that variable after the action is over.

Comment: to add to this, you'll probably want to use localPosition in the event the player moved to a different world position

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How do i use local position ?